# Drop datetime index range from pandas series

Tags: python, series

I have an error with the following code. I am trying to drop a range of date.

The data:

```
timestamp
2020-01-31 04:00:00    0.004923
2020-01-31 05:00:00    0.008942
2020-01-31 06:00:00    0.006695
2020-01-31 07:00:00    0.005026
2020-01-31 08:00:00    0.005724
2020-01-31 09:00:00    0.004783
2020-01-31 10:00:00    0.009536
2020-01-31 11:00:00    0.004379
2020-01-31 12:00:00    0.007783
2020-01-31 13:00:00    0.008245

drop_list = volatility.index[(volatility.index >= '2020-03-12 00:00:00') & (volatility.index <= '2020-03-13 00:00:00')].strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

Index(['2020-03-12 00:00:00', '2020-03-12 01:00:00', '2020-03-12 02:00:00',
       '2020-03-12 03:00:00', '2020-03-12 04:00:00', '2020-03-12 05:00:00'],
      dtype='object')

volatility = volatility.drop(volatility.index[drop_list], inplace=True)
```

The error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: The python operand for logical conjuction is `and`, not &

Comment: the problem is from the last line of code. The operand gives the good range of date in output.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
keep_list = volatility.index[(volatility.index < '2020-03-12 00:00:00') | (volatility.index > '2020-03-13 00:00:00')]
volatility = volatility.loc[keep_list]
```